# List multiplication in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I'm modeling the distribution of hoverflies in an aphid-infested crop field with flower margins. I have a couple of lists which are setup as patch variables as follows:

```
set nl n-values 20 [0];; number of larvae per age (in days)    
set il n-values 20 [0.0001];; individual larvae growth per age (in days)    
set il_growth n-values 20 [0];; growth of larvae per age (in days)
```

I gave the value 0.0001 instead of 0 because previously I got errors regarding the 0.

Every timestap the following happens:

```
to time
  set nl fput item 3 peggs nl ;every day the amount of 4 days old eggs are added to the number of larvae
  set il fput ((item dtl peggs) * weight_hatch) il ;the weight of the larvae that just hatched are calculated by multiplying nl by the weight they have when they hatch
  set il_growth (il * e ^ (g * (aphids)*(1 - (il / weight_max))));;growth individual predator larvae in every age class 
  set larvae nl * il_growth; the total biomass of al larvae in a patch
end
```

The for il_growth comes from the literature and I know that parameters/variables like e, g, aphids and weight_max aren't the problem because this formula work fine before I introduced il.

I'm not sure yet if the approach for biomass is the best way (because of the error of il that I'll describe below), but I figured that the multiplication is possible since nl and il are both lists of the same length.

When I syntax check the code it doesn't give any errors. But when I run it, it says the following: * expected input to be a number but got the list [0 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4] instead. 
The * it points at is the first one in the il_growth formula.

I thought that this could be caused because the code needs il to be a number and not a list. Then I found on google that this could be fixed by the functions 'foreach' or 'map'.

With foreach I tried this:

```
set il_growth foreach il (il * e ^ (g * (aphids)*(1 - (il / weight_max))))
```

This gave the error 'set expected 2 inputs'. I also tried many other configurations with `foreach`, but none worked.

With map I tried this:

```
set il_growth map report_il il

to-report report_il 
  report (il * e ^ (g * (aphids)*(1 - (il / weight_max))))
end
```

This gave me the same error as before: * expected input to be a number but got the list `[0 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4]` instead.

Comment: I have attempted to make your question readable. I formatted the code and moved some of the lengthy commentary into text areas instead so that the code is readable. Please check that the question is still what you intended.

Answer (score 2):

We don't need to know everything you have tried if the attempt didn't help, just enough to understand the code that you are trying to fix and a description of the problem. You definitely can't simply multiply lists the way you have, even if they are the same length. This is a complete model that will generate the same error message:

```
to testme1
  let list1 [1 2 3]
  let list2 [4 5 6]
  print list1 * list2
end
```

If what you are trying to do is multiply the two lists on an item by item basis, then you need `map`. Here is the equivalent model:

```
to testme2
  let list1 [1 2 3]
  let list2 [4 5 6]
  print (map * list1 list2)
end
```

So, if I have understood your question, replace `set larvae nl * il` with `set larvae (map nl * il)`. If that doesn't fix your problem, please edit your question to more clearly identify what you are trying to resolve.

UPDATE: for comment

Okay, from your comment, the line `set il_growth (il * e ^ (g * (aphids)*(1 - (il / weight_max))))` is throwing the error. Just like the `map` is necessary for multiplying lists, it is necessary for more complicated arithmetic. You are multiplying the list il by something with a bunch of values (e, g, aphids, weight_max) and operators and the list il again.

Try replacing with this (untested):

```
set il_growth map [ thisval -> thisval * e ^ (g * (aphids)*(1 - (thisval / weight_max)))) ] il
```

What this (sort of) does is run through the list il, giving the current item to the temporary variable named 'thisval', and does the calculations on the individual value rather than the list. But it applies to the whole list.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Your solution will definitely prevent a future error with the calculation of larvae. However I still have the same problem with the calculation of il_growth. Running the model gives a error for il_growth ''* expected input to be a number but got the list [0 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4 1.0E-4] instead.''. 
By the way, I edited my original post because I saw I made a mistake there: larvae should be 
set larvae nl * il_growth

Comment: same problem, slightly more complicated answer. see update to answer